# MySql: get data from two tables with grouping by Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table with almost same columns, i want to merge them and grouped by date

Table1: order_payments_detail

```
| payment_by |  amount( as Debit in result) | added_on     |
| Ali        |   1000                       | 2014-09-21   |
| Aslam      |   2000                       | 2014-09-25   |
| Akram      |   4000                       | 2014-09-28   |
```

Table2: orders

```
| cust_name  |  amount( as credit in result)| added_on     |
| Shop1      |   1000                       | 2014-09-22   |
| Shop2      |   2000                       | 2014-09-26   |
| Shop3      |   4000                       | 2014-09-29   |
```

Result will be like this

```
| particulars|  debit  |  credit | added_on     |
| Ali        |   1000  |  null   | 2014-09-21   |
| Shop1      |   null  |  1000   | 2014-09-22   |
| Aslam      |   2000  |  null   | 2014-09-25   |
| Shop2      |   null  |  2000   | 2014-09-26   |
| Akram      |   4000  |  null   | 2014-09-28   |
| Shop3      |   null  |  4000   | 2014-09-29   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can readily do this with `union all`:

```
select payment_by, amount as debit, NULL as credit, added_on
from order_payments_detail
union all
select cust_name, NULL, amount, added_on
from orders
order by added_on;
```

By "grouped by date", I assume that you really mean "ordered by date".